# Difference between initialization of empty ArrayBuffer using either "ArrayBuffer.empty[A]" or "ArrayBuffer[A]()" in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have just started learning Scala and I came across two syntax to initialize an empty `ArrayBuffer` which are :

1. `ArrayBuffer.empty[A]`
2. `ArrayBuffer\[A]()`

Is there any difference or preference in terms of usage of them as both are producing the same result when elements are added and played around with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same, as witnessed by the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3987e83b7cf0af7c8dcb17a08e8a040ccbe9a5e5/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.scala#L273):

```
def empty[A]: ArrayBuffer[A] = new ArrayBuffer[A]()
```

Not all types offer the `<type>[Element]()` form of initialization (see `Option` for example) but `<type>.empty[Element]` is pretty universal so it can be used even if it appears redundant and verbose.

Comment: I've deleted my answer to avoid duplication, but you might want to mention that in 2.12 `apply` calls `empty` rather than the other way round.